# Adding to path so that file is available everywhere - bash

Tags: bash, unix, path, terminal, ubuntu-11.10

I am trying to add several directories to my path so that the files in that directory and it's subdirectories are available for me from the command prompt across sessions.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/username/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.1.0/etc/bashrc:/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex:/etc/crontab:/home/username/Research/Dissertation/wigner/ic/L=lambda:/home/username/Research/Dissertation/wigner/ic/L=2lambda:/home/username/Research/Dissertation/wigner/ic/L=3lambda:/home/username/Research/Dissertation/wigner/ic
```

Appending the follwing

```
 /home/username/Research/Dissertation/wigner/ic/L=lambda:/home/username/Research/Dissertation/wigner/ic/L=2lambda:/home/username/Research/Dissertation/wigner/ic/L=3lambda:/home/username/Research/Dissertation/wigner/ic
```

to the `export PATH` line of my `.bashrc` and sourcing it didn't help. What am I doing wrong? When I try to access files from say `/home/username/Research/Dissertation/wigner/ic`, I can't.

I've read a few posts here but they didn't really help at all. Am I missing colons, semicolons, dollar symbols?

Comment: Are the files you are trying to call executable by the user?

Comment: @choroba No, I am trying to concatenate pictures together (eps, pngs etc) using `montage` to compare them side by side. The trouble is, these pictures are in different directories...

Comment: That's not what $PATH (or anything else) can change.

Comment: @choroba So basically I am fracked?

Comment: would all these files have different names?

Comment: @lindelof Yes, they have different names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might be misunderstanding the purpose of `$PATH`. `$PATH` merely tells Bash where to look for executable files and scripts. For example, this command:

```
foo bar.txt
```

will (usually) search `$PATH` for an executable file named `foo`, and these commands:

```
bash foo.sh
. foo.sh
```

will (usually) search `$PATH` for `foo.sh` unless there's a `foo.sh` in the current directory; but these commands:

```
cat foo.txt
vi foo.txt
less foo.txt
```

will *not* search `$PATH` for `foo.txt`.

Furthermore, you write of "the files in that directory and it's subdirectories", but `$PATH` is not useful for subdirectories. Bash will never search `$PATH` if the executable-name contains `/`. For example, this command:

```
foo/bar baz.txt
```

will run `./foo/bar`, and will *not* search `$PATH` for a directory named `foo`.

---

**Edited to add:** So, what you can do instead . . .

Ultimately, you need to include directory information in your `montage` command:

```
cd /home/username/Research/Dissertation/wigner/ic
montage -geometry +4+4 L=3lambda/three.jpg L=2lambda/two.png output.jpg
```

If the directory information is too much of a pain to type every time, you can set up your own variable in `.bashrc`, and then use it explicitly. For example, `.bashrc` might have:

```
export IC=/home/username/Research/Dissertation/wigner/ic
export ICL=$IC/L=lambda
export ICL2=$IC/L=lambda2
export ICL3=$IC/L=lambda3
```

and then you could write:

```
montage -geometry +4+4 $ICL3/three.jpg $ICL2/two.png output.jpg
```

If you don't even want to remember what subdirectory a given file is in, you can use a fileglob:

```
export IC=/home/username/Research/Dissertation/wigner/ic
export ICLs=$IC/L=lambda*
```

and write:

```
montage -geometry +4+4 $ICLs/three.jpg $ICLs/two.png output.jpg
```

letting the shell find it for you. (But of course, this will only work properly if there are no name-conflicts between files in different subdirectores.)

Comment: Ok... so adding to path doesn't help me then... what do I do? I am trying to concatenate pictures together (eps, pngs etc) using montage to compare them side by side. The trouble is, these pictures are in different directories...

Comment: Oh crap, I actually do this to save my path to `dissertation` in a variable called $dissertation! Thanks, I am certain that this would work.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a few variables in your `.bashrc`:

```
H="/home/username/Research/Dissertation/wigner/ic"    
oneLam="$H/L=lambda"
twoLam="$H/L=2lambda"
threeLam="$H/L=3lambda"
```

so that referring to files can be done from anywhere like so:

```
user@box:/some/horrendously/deep/path/$ vi $twoLam/some_file.txt
```